# Google Maps Clustering not working with dynamic data

Tags: android, android-maps, android-maps-utils

I have a problem with the clustering of `GoogleMaps`. In my app im updating the map when the User zooms in or scrolls over the Map. Im using the `OnCameraIdleListener` ([link](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.OnCameraIdleListener)) for this:

```
@Override
public void onCameraIdle() {
   clearItems();
   do API Call
}
```

When this happens im doing an API call with the new radius and im receiving a new list of objects that are visible inside my current radius. After i've received the data im drawing the new POIs to my map. Therefore i iterate over a list and for each element i create a cluster item and add it to the Cluster Manager.

```
CustomClusterItem clusterItem = new CustomClusterItem(new LatLng(item.getLocation().getLatitude(), item.getLocation().getLongitude()), poi); 
mClusterManager.addItem(clusterItem);
```

and after the iteration im calling

```
mClusterManager.cluster();
```

Sadly the clustering does not work. It doesn't matter how far im zooming out of the map for example. Is there something im missing?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just had 4 POIs on my Map and the Clustering just starts with 5 items. So there is no mistake. I just didn't know that there is a size configured by default. If someone wants to achieve clustering with less then 5 items you can use

```
@Override
protected boolean shouldRenderAsCluster(Cluster<T> cluster) {
    //start clustering if at least 2 items overlap
    return cluster.getSize() > 1;
}
```

this method from the DefaultClusterRenderer (https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils/blob/master/library/src/com/google/maps/android/clustering/view/DefaultClusterRenderer.java).

Comment: LOL same problem here. I was struggling because I had only two markers. Thanks for posting the answer.